# Is there any way to ship edge extension with my UWP app?

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge-extension

Is it possible to ship edge extension with my UWP app? I've been working on an app that has edge extension as a core component! I've been wondering if there is any way to directly ship the extension with the UWP app rather than shipping it individually (user would've to download it every time then) in the store.

Also since I'm working on the extension from scratch I don't have an existing version of it on different browsers such as chrome. But I'm asked on the Microsoft request page to provide the link to existing extension. What should I do?

[Microsoft Asking for Existing Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGQeF.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but I never saw any extension for Edge within another app. I'd say your best bet is to submit and see what will happen. If you don't have this extension in other browsers, maybe just leave this field blank?

Comment: Clicking on submit button without any link in the field raises an error saying "fill out this field"

Comment: I see. Maybe you can also ask this on msdn, last time I got a [good answer on extension topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/29c03496-99d0-414a-8c91-7e6509a02e4e/uwp-publishing-an-app-extension?forum=wpsubmit#98e55274-579a-4c82-92cd-760577e5a61c), although it wasn't extension for Edge.

Comment: Ok, posting on MSDN!

Comment: If you are asking about possibilities, your UWP app can contain the extension, and it will be installed with your app. But if you are asking about Store allowing this, I don't think so.